# Failed to spawn hostname main process

Tags: server, plymouth

I have a problem with my ubuntu 10.04.3 server.
After changing user home directory(usermod -m -d /home/username username) my system began work very strange. When try to use "ls -la" command, bash said me that "no such command found".Same output for "cat" command.I tried to restart machine, but after restarting the following messages appeared on screen(something like this):
failed to spawn hostname main process
failed to spawn plymouth main process
failed to spawn hwlock main process
failed to spawn mountall main process

Does everybody knows what happened?
I will very appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy the contents from the old home directory to the new one? At least you may need to copy the old .bashrc.

Try the following:

```
cp /home/old/.bashrc /home/new/.bashrc
```

Better would be to copy even more configuration files to the new home directory.

Background information: bashrc sets up the PATH environment variable, which points to the directories with executables (e.g. cat, ls) - without this file bash, the PATH variable is not set up correctly and bash does not know where to find cat and ls and others, which results in this issue.

You can check the path variable by doing:

```
echo $PATH
```

this should output sth like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```